# XML as an alternative to if else

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

My site has a large number of products in the database. I want to add a product sheet for each product but the database has no set "slot" for it. So I was thinking of writing a php code into the template which checks the part number and use this to load the correct url for the product sheet as a link. For Example

```
<?php
if (strpos($product_sku,'KE15000/12') !== false) {
  $factsheetimage_urlZ='/images/FactsheetBTN.png';
  $factsheetweblink_url="images/factSheetKE15000/12.pdf";
} else if (strpos($product_sku,'KE2000/12') !== false) {
  $factsheetimage_urlZ='/images/FactsheetBTN.png';
  $factsheetweblink_url="images/factSheetKE20000/12.pdf";
} else {
  $factsheetimage_urlZ='/images/blank.png';
}
?>

<div>
  <a href="<?php echo $factsheetweblink_url;?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $factsheetimage_urlZ;?>"></a>
</div>
```

At moment I'm using if else statements (I'm pretty new to PHP) and I was wondering if there's a way to check the `$product_SKU` against an XML document to auto load the correct link rather than doing around 300 if else statements. (`$product_SKU` is the unique product code loaded on each page)

Comment: can you change the database and add a column for this?

Comment: If you have a list of product SKU (e.g. `KE2000/12` ), your link can be something like: `$factsheetweblink_url = 'images/factSheet' . $product_sku . '.pdf';`

Comment: Does this XML document you want to use already exists? or would you be generating it, or writing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about it.

If the `$factsheetweblink_url` can be generated base on the `$product_sku` in some programatic way, that would probably be my first preference. eg. `$factsheetweblink_url = "images/factSheet{$product_sku}.pdf";`

Secondly, adding this column to the database would be a the best option if possible.

Otherwise, the lookup table you mention is certainly possible, XML is one option. If you're writing it by hand, or it needs to be written by a non-technical person would be some considerations for choosing a format. If it's just you, I'd probably use a simpler format (even a plain PHP array).

A simple example of this type of mapping as a PHP array might look like:

sku_url_map.php:

```
<?php
return [
  'KE15000/12' => 'images/factSheetKE15000/12.pdf',
  'KE20000/12' => 'images/factSheetKE20000/12.pdf',
];
```

product_page.php:

```
<?php
$sku_url_map = require 'sku_url_map.php';
// ...
if (isset($sku_url_map[$product_sku])) {
  $factsheetweblink_url = $sku_url_map[$product_sku];
}
```

of course, more complex structures can be used if it's more that a simple 1:1 mapping.